# Node.js Streams vs. Observables

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactive-programming, rxjs, bacon.js

After learning about [Observables](https://github.com/jhusain/asyncgenerator), I find them quite similar to [Node.js streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html). Both have a mechanism of notifying the consumer whenever new data arrives, an error occurs or there is no more data (EOF).

I would love to learn about the conceptual/functional differences between the two. Thanks!

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I wonder why you tagged this with rxjs and bacon? OP seems to refer to the observables from [tag:ecmascript-harmony]

Comment: @Bergi prior knowledge about OP and the question. Basically.

Comment: Lol congrats on the upvotes, but I have no idea why this question didn't get closed. How is this a real question / appropriate for SO.

Comment: @AlexanderMills how is this not an appropriate question for SO? This isn't a "which is your favorite" question; it's asking for the differences between two commonly-used reactive patterns in JS/Node.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Both *Observables* and node.js's *Streams* allow you to solve the same underlying problem: asynchronously process a sequence of values. The main difference between the two, I believe, is related to the context that motivated its appearance. That context is reflected in the terminology and API.

On the *Observables* side you have an extension to EcmaScript that introduces the reactive programming model. It tries to fill the gap between value generation and asynchronicity with the minimalist and composable concepts of `Observer` and `Observable`.

On node.js and *Streams* side you wanted to create an interface for the asynchronous and performant processing of network streams and local files. The terminology derives from that initial context and you get `pipe`, `chunk`, `encoding`, `flush`, `Duplex`, `Buffer`, etc. By having a pragmatic approach that provides explicit support for particular use cases you lose some ability to compose things because it's not as uniform. For example, you use `push` on a `Readable` stream and `write` on a `Writable` although, conceptually, you are doing the same thing: publishing a value.

So, in practice, if you look at the concepts, and if you use the option `{ objectMode: true }`, you can match `Observable` with the `Readable` stream and `Observer` with the `Writable` stream. You can even create some simple adapters between the two models.

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
var Writable = require('stream').Writable;
var util = require('util');

var Observable = function(subscriber) {
    this.subscribe = subscriber;
}

var Subscription = function(unsubscribe) {
    this.unsubscribe = unsubscribe;
}

Observable.fromReadable = function(readable) {
    return new Observable(function(observer) {
        function nop() {};

        var nextFn = observer.next ? observer.next.bind(observer) : nop;
        var returnFn = observer.return ? observer.return.bind(observer) : nop;
        var throwFn = observer.throw ? observer.throw.bind(observer) : nop;

        readable.on('data', nextFn);
        readable.on('end', returnFn);
        readable.on('error', throwFn);

        return new Subscription(function() {
            readable.removeListener('data', nextFn);
            readable.removeListener('end', returnFn);
            readable.removeListener('error', throwFn);
        });
    });
}

var Observer = function(handlers) {
    function nop() {};

    this.next = handlers.next || nop;
    this.return = handlers.return || nop;
    this.throw = handlers.throw || nop;
}

Observer.fromWritable = function(writable, shouldEnd, throwFn) {
    return new Observer({
        next: writable.write.bind(writable), 
        return: shouldEnd ? writable.end.bind(writable) : function() {}, 
        throw: throwFn
    });
}
```

You may have noticed that I changed a few names and used the simpler concepts of `Observer` and `Subscription`, introduced here, to avoid the overload of reponsibilities done by *Observables* in `Generator`. Basically, the `Subscription` allows you to unsubscribe from the `Observable`. Anyway, with the above code you can have a `pipe`.

```
Observable.fromReadable(process.stdin).subscribe(Observer.fromWritable(process.stdout));
```

Compared with `process.stdin.pipe(process.stdout)`, what you have is a way to combine, filter, and transform streams that also works for any other sequence of data. You can achieve it with `Readable`, `Transform`, and `Writable` streams but the API favors subclassing instead of chaining `Readable`s and applying functions. On the `Observable` model, For example, transforming values corresponds to applying a transformer function to the stream. It does not require a new subtype of `Transform`.

```
Observable.just = function(/*... arguments*/) {
    var values = arguments;
    return new Observable(function(observer) {
        [].forEach.call(values, function(value) {
            observer.next(value);
        });
        observer.return();
        return new Subscription(function() {});
    });
};

Observable.prototype.transform = function(transformer) {
    var source = this;
    return new Observable(function(observer) {
        return source.subscribe({
            next: function(v) {
                observer.next(transformer(v));
            },
            return: observer.return.bind(observer),
            throw: observer.throw.bind(observer)
        });
    });
};

Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).transform(JSON.stringify)
  .subscribe(Observer.fromWritable(process.stdout))
```

The conclusion? It's easy to introduce the reactive model and the `Observable` concept anywhere. It's harder to implement an entire library around that concept. All those little functions need to work together consistently. After all, the [ReactiveX](http://reactivex.io/) project is still going at it. But if you really need to send the file content to the client, deal with encoding, and zip it then the support it's there, in NodeJS, and it works pretty well.

Comment: I really am not sure about this whole "extension to Ecmascript thing". RxJS is just a library, same with RxJava, etc. Eventually, in ES7 or ES8 there might be some keywords in ES/JS that pertain to Observables, but they are certainly not part of the language, and certainly not when you answered the question in 2015.

Comment: Is RX implementation support lossless backpressure? 
For example if nodejs read stream in the paused mode then we can use the `read()` method to read from the stream on demand.
And the `drain event` can signal that the writable stream can receive more data.

Comment: I wish I could understand things